# Canonical question for calling non-exported Linux kernel functions from a kernel module

Tags: discussion, canonical

I've been wandering around [linux-kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux-kernel) for quite a while now, reading questions almost daily and answering interesting ones. In this time, I've seen a fair amount of users asking help about calling functions that are not exported by the kernel from a kernel module.

Here are some examples:

- [How can I reference non-exported Linux kernel functions from a kernel module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157442/how-can-i-reference-non-exported-linux-kernel-functions-from-a-kernel-module)
- [How my custom module on linux 3.2.28 can make a call to print_cpu_info?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691123/how-my-custom-module-on-linux-3-2-28-can-make-a-call-to-print-cpu-info/19697575#19697575)
- [Proper way of getting address of sys_call_table in recent kernels that do not export kallsyms_lookup_name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70930059/proper-way-of-getting-address-of-sys-call-table-in-recent-kernels-that-do-not-ex/70934260#70934260)
- [LSM-Howto: Kernelmodule with non exported functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262910/lsm-howto-kernelmodule-with-non-exported-functions)
- [How to intercept not exported kernel function from loadable kernel module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39633883/how-to-intercept-not-exported-kernel-function-from-loadable-kernel-module)
- [How do I interact with sysfs or a driver that exports to sysfs in my own kernel module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72599892/how-do-i-interact-with-sysfs-or-a-driver-that-exports-to-sysfs-in-my-own-kernel#comment128295943_72599892)

I think a canonical Q&A for such questions would be useful, however none of the above qualify IMHO, because they are (1) often limited to a specific problem, and (2) even when they are not, while some of the provided answers are good, they all suggest different solutions, so there's bits and pieces scattered around, but no real "complete" answer.

I'd be willing to sit down and write a self-answered Q&A post explaining all possible approaches under different scenarios, but I thought I'd ask here first.

Is there any good Q&A that I missed to be used as canonical for this? Or should I actually post one and then start using that?

---

For reference, here is a draft of what I think a good canonical question for this could look like:

> I am developing a Linux kernel module which would need to rely on some kernel function (or global symbol) that is not exported by the kernel for modules to use (i.e. there is no `EXPORT_SYMBOL()` for it).
>
> Indeed, if I try to compile my module, I get an error that looks like this:
>
> ```
> $ make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
> make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.0-14-amd64'
>   CC [M]  /home/user/mymodule/mymodule.c
>   MODPOST /home/user/mymodule/Module.symvers
> ERROR: modpost: "some_function" [/home/user/mymodule/mymodule.ko] undefined!
> ...
> ```
>
> Would it be possible to call such a function anyway? If so, how?
>
> I understand that I should not rely on unexported functions in my module, but I am certainly not going to submit a patch to get my module included in the kernel source. I am writing a module for educational purposes, and not for production use.
>
> What are my options?

Comment: Why not make one, write it in the tag and reference it, it will get noticed save as bookmark and then used as dupe marker

Comment: @nbk yeah that's more or less what I was thinking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tag "linux-kernel" is among my watched tags too, and I am perfectly aware about the problem with using non-exported symbols.

The [third question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70930059/3440745) seems to be good base for being canonical.

Its current content is short and isn't polluted with unneeded details. While the part about "recent kernels" is important for the question, it can be easy edited out from the title and moved into the question's body.

The question has your answer with several solutions.

The question has even the [other's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71792997/3440745), which *looks* like a possible solution too (while I heard about kprobes a lot, I am not an expert with them). Yes, that solution is quite complex, but the problem itself has no simple solution. (Except: "stop using functions which are not intended to be used outside the kernel").

> ... write a self-answered Q&A post explaining **all possible approaches** under different scenarios

While I am agree about needing of **single question** on this problem, I don't think it needs a **single answer**. E.g. canonical question for [undefined reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) error has **many answers** written by different authors.

Comment: It's true, the question you link seems ok, but it talks about a particular symbol. Are you suggesting to change its title (and maybe the body a little bit) in order to make it the canonical question for this? It also only covers "recent kernels that do not support kallsyms_lookup_name". I was trying to find (or write) a canonical Q&A that *at least* covered both cases (pre/post `kallsyms_*` functions being unexported).

Comment: Yes, `sys_call_table` can be edited out from the question's title too. Noting it in the question's body provides a non-desired detail (the problem about syscall hooking is even more controversial than using non-exported symbols), but otherwise even the original question doesn't look like about syscall hooking only.

Comment: Hmm, do you really want to cover `kallsyms_*` approaches too? I understand that there are many distros (even production ones) which use older kernels, but writing a **new** answer for that case doesn't look very useful. In any case, even if the question is stated about kernels with non-exported kallsyms functionality, nothing prevents to write an answer which uses that functionality. Some people could downvote that answer as "not corresponded to the question", but I don't find such downvotes as very important.

Comment: Well I guess that mentioning the `kallsyms_*` approach in my existing answer with a link to another decent answer on the topic wouldn't hurt. I agree that we don't really need a *new* answer covering that.

Comment: I went ahead and modified the title of the question as you suggest, also adding more information to my already existing answer. Seems like a decent canonical question for future questions about this. The question title is a bit long, but seems ok to me, feel free to improve it if you wish.